# Как проверить если ли контент в блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-ui, jquery-form

Вот код!

Почему-то не срабатывает `else`.  Логика такова,  если блок пустой мы добавляем классы  или же если он имеет, мы убираем классы.

```js
function isEmpty(el) {
  return !$.trim(el.html())
}
if (isEmpty($('.width-content-pay'))) {
  $('.width-content-pay').addClass('removeWidth');
  $('.width-content-bill-status').addClass('empty');
} else {
  removeClas();
}

function removeClas() {
  $('.width-content-pay').has("a");
  $('.width-content-bill-status').removeClass('empty');
  $('.width-content-pay').removeClass('removeWidth');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li class="width-content-data">{{ _("Дата создания") }}</li>
    <li class="width-content-id">{{ _("ID счета") }}</li>
    <li class="width-content-number">{{ _("Сумма счета") }}</li>
    <li class="width-content-shop">{{ _("Магазин") }}</li>
    <li class="width-content-amount">{{ _("Сумма к оплате") }}</li>
    <li class="width-content-bill-status">{{ _("Статус") }}</li>
    <li class="width-content-pay"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
{% for bill in bills %}
<div class="accordion" id="accordion_{{ bill.id }}" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Card header -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading_{{ bill.id }}">
      <ul class="reports-detail">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{{ bill.id }}" href="#collapse_{{ bill.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_{{ bill.id }}">
          <li class="width-content-data" data-atribute="{{ _(" Дата создания ") }}"><i class="collapsed fa fa-angle-down more-block"></i>{{ bill.created_text }}</li>
        </a>
        <li class="width-content-id" data-atribute="{{ _(" ID счета ") }}">{{ bill.id }}</li>
        <li class="width-content-number" data-atribute="{{ _(" Сумма счета ") }}">{{ bill.shop_amount_text }}</li>
        <li class="width-content-shop" data-atribute="{{ _(" Магазин ") }}"><a href="{{ bill.shop_url }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{ bill.shop_name }}</a></li>
        <li class="width-content-amount" data-atribute="{{ _(" Сумма к оплате ") }}">{{ bill.payer_price_text }}</li>
        <li class="width-content-bill-status" data-atribute="{{ _(" Статус ") }}"><i class="{{ bill.status_class }}" aria-hidden="true" title="{{ bill.status_text }}"></i></li>
        <li class="width-content-pay" data-atribute="{{ _(" Оплатить ") }}">
          {% if bill.actions %}
          <a class="pink-text accent-2 lead bill-action" title="Оплатить" href="{{ url_for('bills.bill', bill_id=bill.encode_id, lang_code=g.current_lang) }}"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> {% endif %}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: > У меня все работает. Проверь если JQUERY подключен.

Comment: все подключено(

Comment: Тогда после обновлении контента ты должен еще раз вызвать те методы что ты написал.

Comment: в плані?)) мож написать як?)

Comment: думаю найдешь ответ в коде что написал я

Comment: да но ты вызываешь функции при клике) у меня же ситуация другая! у меня с бека приходять данные и нужно проверять уже если ли в <li> что то или нету 
если нету добавляем клас! если есть то убираем клас

Comment: isEmpty($('.width-content-pay li'))

Comment: $('.width-content-pay').html($('input').val());

Comment: $('.width-content-pay').html($('input').val());

у меня нету инпута) возможно если я буду смотеть в етот клас и на тег а? работать будет?

Comment: Я добавил input чтобы вы могли его протестировать и покозать, как это работает с контентом и без контента.. Я думаю, проблема в селекторе у вас.

Comment: увы но ваш метод) не подходит) всеравно когда есть что то в класе width-content-pay у меня не убирает класы которые я добавляю

Comment: покажыте мне html-код

Comment: у Вас `removeClas` просто вызывает `$('.width-content-pay').has("a");` что возвращает булиан. В этом вся ошибка. Вам нужно как минимум добавить блок с проверкой

Comment: добавтить if ($('.width-content-pay').has("a")){}